What is the difference between parallelism and coincidence (if any)?
As far as I know, parallelism in Euclidean Geometry is defined as two or more straight lines which do not intersect each another (or meet at infinity). The thing is, in all the Mathematics Textbooks I have, it is written that coincidence of two straight lines implies that the two lines are parallel to each other.
However, there arises a question here: if parallel lines never intersect, and coincident lines intersect at infinite points, how does coincidence imply parallelism?
Well, I thought about it, and I came to three conclusions:

Parallelism never talks about two distinct geometrical entities.
Coincidence talks about features or parts of features occupying the same space; again, nothing about distinct entities.
I have thought of a solution to this problem. It goes something like so:

Assuming two distinct parallel entities, their coincidence is achieved when the perpendicular distance between them tends to zero.
Is this a correct way to think about it?

Related (duplicate?): "What is a parallel line?" In particular, see my (over-a-decade-old!) answer.

Nice. But can I approach the concept of coincidence starting from parallelism using limits (as I have done)?
